# Wheelset upgrade

Tags: upgrades, gravel, giant, wheels

I own a 2016 Giant Revolt (https://www.giant-bicycles.com/int/revolt-1-2016) and I was looking to buy a new gravel wheelset. Currently I have the 2016 version of Giant P-X2 Disc Wheelset, [F]32H [R]32H. My aim was to upgrade my wheels so to keep the ones I have as a backup. Any suggestions? I was aiming at a 200-250 EUR price range which should be more than enough to buy some sweet stuff.